# MVC Routes - Urls based on fixed list of parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have a large group of URLs I need to 301 redirect. I've set up a number of routes as 'catches' for the various 301s but I somehow seem to have created a redirect loop.

Can someone confirm - would the following be a valid url and enforce the parameter to **ONLY** be from the pipe delimited list (i.e. if the values aren't matched, the route won't catch)

```
routes.MapRoute("MyRouteName", // Route name
    "first-folder/second-folder/{param1}", // URL with parameters
    new
    {
        controller = "Redirect",
        action = "MyRedirectHandler",
        newRouteName = "mynewroute",
        folder1= "foo",
        folder2 = "bar",
        set = "option1|option2|option3"
    });
```

so, in this case:

`mysite.com/first-folder/second-folder/option1` => `mysite.com/mynewroute/foo/bar`

`mysite.com/first-folder/second-folder/option2` => `mysite.com/mynewroute/foo/bar`

`mysite.com/first-folder/second-folder/option88` => `404`

the params in `set` are used only to catch the url, my `MyRedirectHandler` is a controller action that will do the 301 to the route i specify in `newRouteName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, 
I posted too soon. For anyone experiencing a similar issue this loop was down to the difference between Route param defaults and param constraints. The example above should be:

```
routes.MapRoute("MyRouteName", // Route name
  "first-folder/second-folder/{param1}", // URL with parameters
new
{
    controller = "Redirect",
    action = "MyRedirectHandler",
    newRouteName = "mynewroute",
    folder1= "foo",
    folder2 = "bar" 
},  //param defaults
new {
    set = "option1|option2|option3"
} //param constraints
);
```